# Install python 2 lib using python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, coherence-toolkit

I have this lib, Coherence ([link](https://github.com/coherence-project/Coherence)) and it was made in python 2. So I want to know how can I install this lib in python 3.

To install it, I just need to run "sudo python setup.py install"

I've tried to use python-future on my main script, where I use the lib, but it still give me syntax errors on dependencies.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Use virtual environment, visit this link http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ for details.

Comment: But then I wont install it on python 3. I have a project running on python 3 witch I want to integrate with this lib. That's why I need to install it on python 3.